# How do I make a div on top of fabric objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

**HTML:**

```
<div  style='position:absolute; left:0px; width:100%; height:100px; 
background-color:red;z-order:9999;'>
</div>            
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

**JS:**

```
// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 5
});

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    fill: '#269926',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
}));

var obj = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 20,
    top: 20,
    fill: '#555555',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
canvas.sendToBack(obj)
```

here is a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orihadar/F6UU4/41/)

as you can see in the demo, the red div is in the back.

How do I bring it in front of all the fabricJS objects ?

as you can see I tried using sendToBack and tried changing the z-order but no luck.

Comment: Is that work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/F6UU4/42/

Comment: Or try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/F6UU4/43/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo for z-index:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F6UU4/42)

```
 <div  style='position:absolute; left:0px; width:100%; height:100px; background-color:red;z-order:9999; top:0'>
</div>     
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" style='z-index:-1'></canvas>
```

and demo for dom manuplation:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F6UU4/43)

Comment: Thank you very much but I need some clarifications: In the first demo all you did is moving the DIV to be after the canvas? In The second demo I dont see the fabricjs objects not any JS additional code

Comment: Yes, on second demo I just add the sytle attr for canvas object. Because fabric js copy all styles and cover canvas with div.

Comment: @user2299401, please don't forget 'make answer correct', thank you :)